# Cygwin: Linux kernel make clean not working

Tags: linux-kernel, cygwin

I am trying to compile Linux kernel on Windows using Cygwin. When I try make distclean it gives me the following error:

```
 make distclean
 make[1]: *** Documentation/Kbuild: Is a directory.  Stop.
 Makefile:1188: recipe for target '_clean_Documentation' failed
 make: *** [_clean_Documentation] Error 2
```

Comment: Kernel version? If kernel is not vanilla(taken from `kernel.org`), where you get it?

Comment: Hi Tsyvarev, kernel taken from kernel.org

Comment: And what version of the kernel you take?

Comment: According to https://unrouted.io/2016/08/09/docker-osx-linux-kernel-building/ it's due to a case-insensative filesystem

Answer (score 4):

Had the similar problem.

As was mentioned by [@Daniel Griscom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2190921/daniel-griscom) and [@Sniffleh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3147010/sniffleh), it really looks like the problem due to a case-insensitive filesystem, and fsutil really can resolve this problem.

Let me share some useful commands:

- If `fsutil.exe file SetCaseSensitiveInfo YourDestinationFolder enable` don't work, try to 
  use `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux` in PowerShell.
- fsutil can't enable case sensitive recursively, so you can use `(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory).FullName | ForEach-Object {fsutil.exe file setCaseSensitiveInfo $_ enable}` in PowerShell.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it provides a command to fully use the fsutil.exe to fix this issue :)

Answer (score 1):

According to [unrouted.io/2016/08/09/docker-osx-linux-kernel-building](http://unrouted.io/2016/08/09/docker-osx-linux-kernel-building) it's due to a case-insensitive filesystem (which Windows is, as is macOS).

Answer (score 1):

Try using fsutil.exe file queryCaseSensitiveInfo  enable?
Source: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/per-directory-case-sensitivity-and-wsl/